# Azure Cloud Shell - Storage Creation Failed

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

Seems each time I try to use an existing share for Cloud Shell, it gives me the annoying error

> Error: 400 {"error": "code":"AccountPropertyCannotBeUpdated","message":"The property 'kind'
>   was specified in the input, but it cannot be updated."}}.  I have
>   tried just creating a Resource Group and then a Storage Account before
>   hand and then selecting to create a new File share but this too fails.
>   I wanted to use a single share for storing Cloud Shell img files for
>   each of the members of my team so we could easily share files.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a bad behavior. Please use the standard options for initialize the Cloud Shell and verify your Azure account type.

Comment: Actually, working with the Azure team now and it appears to be a bug.

Comment: I am having this problem.  Every time I try to create the storage account it says the account is already there, but it is not.  Also each time I try to change the name to create a different one, it says is already there.  But I don't see these storage accounts that it says is there.